# IBM Rational - indentation available in Rational 9.6.0.6?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, ibm-rational

Is this type of indentation available in Rational 9.6.0.6 (2019)?
I can't find it in View options.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try CTRL + SHIFT + O , available from 9.6.0.2

Comment: + position yourself in relavant place in the code.

wow!